# How to setup an asp.net website from one server to another server subdomain

Tags: asp.net

I have transferred a ASP .net website from one server to another server subdomain but when I access the site Default.aspx page then instead of page rendering it show all the code of the page.

The original site is http://www.bestmailing.com/Default.aspx and the server I have setup is site url is http://www.1bz.com/bm/Default.aspx

Can anyone please help me with setting the website environment correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You must add on the server that default.aspx is home page and also .aspx type

Comment: also check if the new server supports asp.net websites at all.

Comment: @S.Petrosov can you please tell me what do you mean to say?

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik how can I check that I my server support asp.net

Comment: @vikas https://www.google.am/search?q=how+to+check+if+server+supports+asp.net&oq=how+to+check+if+server+supports+as&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.18535j0j4&client=ms-android-micromax&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8